# Overlay and jQuery don't work, what should I do?

Tags: 7, javascript, modal-dialogs

I have installed Drupal 7 on a local computer on stack called Denwer (similar to WAMP) and Windows 7; I see that all pages load without Overlay module (it is on, on modules page).
I guess that  jQuery does not work at all: Views slideshow doesn't work, when I add node all parameters load in a list instead of paging-listing mode.

I cleared all caches, reinstalled Drupal 7 using the development snapshot, clean-installed Denwer: all this doesn't work.

I remember I didn't have such problems on Windows XP.

Comment: Did you try adding, for example, "#overlay=admin/appearance" to an URL and see what happens. I sometimes noticed the overlay is not show, but the theme I set as administrative theme is used for the setting page.

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen [Overlay and jQuery dont work on Win 7, but work on XP](http://drupal.org/node/1129572)?

The last comment reported in that report is the following one:

> Problem resolved. I still don't know why this problem arise, but after Windows 7 latest updates installed (on 18 apr 2011) overlay and jquery now working.

Answer (score 1):

Check your URL.

The ovelay is enabled by URL in this way: `http://localhost/yoursite/#overlay=admin/appearance`; if you write `http://localhost/yoursite/admin/appearance` the overlay is "disabled".

Also check if the you have the "access overlay" permission in order to see the administrative pages on the overlay.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but i tried this too. - no matter. 
I only see front page of the site and no any overlay at all. I am superadmin, and have permission to Overlay.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed I had the exact same problem when I made the mistake of installing a test site in a folder with a space in the name; as soon as I went back and corrected the problem (so the URL did not contain any %20 character) the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the overlay to work as well after I upgraded Drupal 7 to a newer version.  Issue turned out to be some changes I had made to .htaccess.  Reverted back to the original .htaccess, and the overlays appeared again.

This was with Server 2003, IIS 6.5 (I think?).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Drupal 8, if you are using WAMP than go to apache modules, and enable **rewrite_module** it solved the problem for me right away!

I figured the problem was there because kiamlaluno said (in this post) that is't a URL issue...

Hope this works for whoever googles this problem in the future